# JavaFX TableView doesn't show the content

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to insert some values in a TableView, but it doesn't display the text in the columns, even though they're not empty because there are three rows (the same number of items I inserted in the TableView) which are clickable.

[image: I can select raws but I can't see them]

I have the class "*ClientiController*" which is the controller of the fxml file, and these are the declaration of the TableView and the columns of the tableView.

```
@FXML // fx:id="clientitable"
private TableView clientitable; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="nome"
private TableColumn nome; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="id"
private TableColumn id; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

@FXML // fx:id="telefono"
private TableColumn telefono; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
```

I call on the *initialize()* method a function, called *loadTable()* that adds the content to the TableView.

*loadTable* is in the same class "*ClientiController*" and this is its implementation:

```
    @FXML
void loadTable()
{
    //Cliente
    try {
        List<String> clienti = (List<String>) fc.processRequest("ReadClienti");
        ObservableList<String> clienteData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(clienti);

        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cliente, String>("id"));
        nome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cliente, String>("nome"));
        cognome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cliente, String>("cognome"));
        telefono.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cliente, String>("n_tel"));


        System.out.println(clienteData);
        clientitable.setItems(clienteData);

        } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException
            | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

In the class `Cliente` I have these strings:

```
private String id, nome, cognome, n_tel;
```

And the get and set functions for each String element, which take the values from the Database.
In this Class I also have the readAll method (`ReadClienti`).
In `List<Cliente> clienti` in the function `loadTable()` there is the result of the readAll method, and the function returns an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` type.

If I select the first raw (even if I cannot see the text inside the columns) and then print it like this,

```
ArrayList<String> person =  (ArrayList<String>) clientitable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(person);
```

it all works fine and it prints the value I inserted as first, so I know the values are actually in that table.

I also tried to change the private String strings in this class into SimpleStringProperty like I saw in other discussions in here but nothing changed.

How can I make the tableView display its content?

**Edit:**
I think the problem is in the assignment

```
            List<String> clienti = (List<String>) fc.processRequest("ReadClienti");
```

in the first raw of *loadTable()*, because I cannot cast a type `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` into a `List<String>`.
But the `ObservableList<String>` in which I have to put the values to populate the ListView only gets Lists or simple ArrayLists as input.
How can I transform my `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` variable to match the ObservableList type?

Comment: The code snippets you have posted are not compatible with each other. If `loadTable` is executed, then the code you say displays the selected item, you would get a `ClassCastException` (because a `Cliente` is not an `ArrayList`). Create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: I edited the question and I found what I think might be the only problem, but I cannot find a solution to that (I wrote it at the end of the post)

Comment: You need to decide how you are representing your data and fix your types accordingly. I would probably start by removing all *raw type* declarations, e.g. `private TableView clientiTable;` should be `private TableView<Something> clientiTable;`. The compiler should be giving you warnings here. If you make those changes, you will get compile errors where the types are incompatible, so it will be easier to find and fix those errors. It's impossible to help much more than that without a [MCVE].

Comment: I solved the problem creating a constructor in the class Clienti, that way I could create objects of the type Clienti and refer to them with the get functions.. That thing was missing in my code. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Your class "Cliente" does not have getters and setters. And also take care about names of getters and setters of the parameters. getter and setter should not different from parameters declared above.
For example:

```
private String Clienteid;
private String ClienteName;

public getClientid(){
    return Clienteid;
}
```

This line of code require getters and setter of the class...

```
id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cliente, String>("id"));
nome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cliente, String>("nome"));
```